# CSS Transition/Animation Prefix trouble

Tags: html, css, animation, browser

I'm trying to get this CSS alternative for a slide show animation for customer Testimonials. I can get it to work in IE and Firefox but it will not work in Chrome. Does anybody know if i need to use some prefixes to fix this issue?

Here is a [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dshojaei/auuav7L8/embedded/result/).

```
<div class="css-slideshow">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://www.offsetprinting.com/img/custom_images/test_slide1.jpg" alt="class-header-css3" width="1192" height="497" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-172" /><figcaption><strong>CSS3:</strong></figcaption> 
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://www.offsetprinting.com/img/custom_images/test_slide2.jpg" alt="class-header-semantics" width="1192" height="497" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-179" /><figcaption><strong>Semantics:</strong></figcaption> 
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://www.offsetprinting.com/img/custom_images/test_slide3.jpg" alt="class-header-offline" width="1192" height="497" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-178" /><figcaption><strong>Offline &amp; Storage:</strong></figcaption> 
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://www.offsetprinting.com/img/custom_images/test_slide1.jpg" alt="class-header-device" width="1192" height="497" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-177" /><figcaption><strong>Device Access:</strong></figcaption> 
    </figure>
<figure>
        <img src="http://www.offsetprinting.com/img/custom_images/test_slide2.jpg" alt="class-header-connectivity" width="1192" height="497" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-176" /><figcaption><strong>Connectivity:</strong></figcaption> 
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://www.offsetprinting.com/img/custom_images/test_slide3.jpg" alt="class-header-multimedia" width="1192" height="497" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-175" /><figcaption><strong>Multimedia:</strong></figcaption> 
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://www.offsetprinting.com/img/custom_images/test_slide1.jpg" alt="class-header-3d" width="1192" height="497" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-174" /><figcaption><strong>3D, Graphics &amp; Effects:</strong></figcaption> 
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://www.offsetprinting.com/img/custom_images/test_slide2.jpg" alt="class-header-performance" width="1192" height="497" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-173" /><figcaption><strong>Performance &amp; Integration:</strong></figcaption> 
    </figure>
  </div>  


body{
font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
  font-weight: 300;
}
.css-slideshow{
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1192px;
  height: 497px;
  margin: 5em auto .5em auto;
}
.css-slideshow figure{
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 1192px;
  height: 497px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
}
.css-slideshow img{
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #666;
}
.css-slideshow figcaption{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0,0,0, .3);
  font-size: .8em;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.css-slideshow-attr{
  max-width: 1192px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: .7em;
  font-style: italic;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.css-slideshow-attr a{
  color: #666;
}
.css-slideshow figure{
  opacity:0;
}
figure:nth-child(1) {
  animation: xfade 48s 42s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(2) {
  animation: xfade 48s 36s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(3) {
  animation: xfade 48s 30s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(4) {
  animation: xfade 48s 24s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(5) {
  animation: xfade 48s 18s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(6) {
  animation: xfade 48s 12s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(7) {
  animation: xfade 48s 6s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(8) {
  animation: xfade 48s 0s infinite;
}

@keyframes xfade{
  0%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
  10.5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  12.5%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
</
```

Comment: You shouldn't need a prefix for recent versions of Chrome, no. What exactly would the expected animation do?

Comment: It's a pure CSS slideshow. The site i'm re-designing does not let you use Jquery for animation affects. So i'm doing everything with CSS work a rounds.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome is a webkit browser, try using the webkit prefix (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp) like this:

```
figure:nth-child(8) {
    animation: xfade 48s 0s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: xfade 48s 0s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes xfade{
  0%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
  10.5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  12.5%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes xfade{
  0%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
  10.5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  12.5%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: How about Safari? Safari is where i'm having the most problems.

Comment: Chrome, Safari, and Opera are all webkit browsers, so this should work for all of them. Is it not?

Comment: That's the frustrating part of this. I'm having this problem in Safari. Is there a webkit i'm not aware of?

Comment: Can you view it in Safari your self? I just tested it on a few other macs in the office, and still no luck.

Comment: The fiddle you linked to in you post doesn't have the `-webkit-animation` rules that I posted, just the `animation` ones, can you post a fiddle with the updated code?

Comment: You have some extraneous start and end tags before and after the `@-webkit-keyframes xfade` declaration. After removing those the animation worked fine for me in Safari

Comment: You fixed it! Thanks man. I'm getting a little of a delay after a few slides on Safari, but at least it's showing now.